# Weird behaviour with updateViewLayout in Android Jelly Bean service

Tags: android, animation, service, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have started working on an app that uses an overlay service to display a utility sidebar on the phone.

What I did was to add a small arrow handle to the right side of the screen, and when the user swipes over it, the sidebar shows up.

This worked without issue up to Jelly Bean. Starting with JB, the entire process of showing the sidebar started to become animated. Which would be very cool, if it were not animating all over the place.

What I did to show and hide the sidebar was a simple updateViewLayout command as below.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        handlesize, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
wm.updateViewLayout(mOverlay, params);
handleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.handle);
isCompact=true;
```

This piece of code hides the sidebar. The handlesize variable is the width of the handle. The wm variable is the window manager. So basically, what I do is only show the width of the handle, so anything else that might be next to the handle(the sidebar is not visible). I also use WRAP_CONTENT for the height, to make sure the only part that absorbs touch events is the area used by the handle, so as to not block off the entire right hand side of the screen from registering touches.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
wm.updateViewLayout(mOverlay, params);
handleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.handle_back);
isCompact=false;
```

This is the code that displays the sidebar. The width of the whole view is set to WRAP_CONTENT, so it shows all the content, and the height is set to MATCH_PARENT, because the sidebar is full height when it's visible.

Now normally, this code should instantly switch between one width and height set to the other width and height set, nothing in between. But since Jelly Bean, this has started doing this through some weird animation. I'm not sure, but it may have something to do with Project Butter.

In the link below, you can see some frames of the animation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzZGO.png

If I set the height of the view, even when closed, to MATCH_PARENT, then the animation is just on the horizontal plane, so right to left, which does look nice. The problem with that is I don't want to block the entire right hand side of the screen. There are a lot of uses for sliding from the right in other apps that might run under the service, like switching tabs in Chrome.

So my question is, do you have any idea what I should do to stop this behavior, or, even better, to use it to my advantage in order to make the sidebar do some smooth animations, but in a way that works on Android 2.2 and above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the exact same issue in my service. Did you manage to find a solution to this? Appreciate if you could share any insight.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I have asked around, but haven't gotten any answers. Did you manage to find anything in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, I did find a solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Since JB Android has added window animations to layout changes. If you disable window animation in Developer settings, the behavior will stop. Also, you cannot disable/enable this programmatically (requires system permission if I remember correctly), so the solution is to remove the view completely and attach it again. Instead of `wm.updateViewLayout(view,params)` you have to `wm.removeView(view)` and then `wm.addView(view,params)`.